# How can I correctly bind event handlers to class methods?

Tags: javascript, class, events

I prefer to put all functionality of a piece of my webapp in a class, but I am struggling to "correctly" bind DOM handlers.

What I have now, that is working is this:

```
class MyModule {
    constructor() {
       this.somedata = somevalue;

       let me = this;
       $("#somediv").on("click", function() {
          // 'this' here refers to the div in the DOM
          me.somediv_onClick(this);
       }
    }

    somediv_onClick(divElement) {
       // 'this' here refers to the MyModule object
       // we can use this.somedata
       let div = $(divElement);
       div.html(this.somedata);
    }
}
```

But, that feels a little clunky with the all `let me = this`, etc.

So I tried this construction (more concise, but unfortunately works a little different):

```
class MyModule {
    constructor() {
       $("#somediv").on("click", this.somediv_onClick);
    }

    somediv_onClick(event) {
       // 'this' here refers to the clicked element in the DOM
       // there is no reference to the MyModule object
       let div = $(this);
       div.html( ... ? ...);
    }
}
```

How can I do this in a clean way?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: You can use `.bind()` or else use `=>` functions to make sure `this` is not re-bound.

Comment: @VLAZ `$("#somediv").on("click", e => this.somediv_onClick(e));`

Comment: A completely different approach, since you're using jQuery anyway, is to attach `this` to the elements related to an instance of your class, and then use delegated event handlers. The handlers can retrieve the object reference (`this`) via `.data()`, and call whatever methods they want.